# Objective-C - NSTimeZone 2 hours wrong?

Tags: objective-c, nstimezone

I'm using the following code to set my timezone to Stockholm, Europe.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Stockholm"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSDate *webUpdateDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-07-22 22:10"]; 
// Outputs "2011-07-22 20:10 +0000"
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: I doubt anyone on Stack Overflow knows why you're setting the timezone to Stockholm.  :)

Comment: If it is consistently like that then why not set it back 2hrs manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're inspecting the date using `NSLog`. An `NSDate` object represents an absolute time -- it has no notion of time zone, so when it is asked for its `description`, it displays as if it were a time in GMT. If you want that absolute time represented for the Stockholm time zone, you need to use the date formatter again:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:webUpdateDate]);
```

Since the date was originally created via the formatter, which already had its time zone set to Stockholm, I believe this will give you the same string that you used for input: `@"2011-07-22 22:10"`.